# Why isn't my function being called on submit?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Trying to call validateAndConfirm function on submit of below form but nothing is happening - please help :(

HTML Form-

```
<div id='form' class='center text'>
            <form method='post' onsumbmit='validateAndConfirm'>
                <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder='Your first name...' autocomplete='given-name' required>
                <br>
                <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder='Your last name...' autocomplete='family-name' required>
                <br>
                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@mail.co.nz..." autocomplete='off' required>
                <br>
                <label for="confemail">Confirm Email Address:</label>
                <input type="email" id="confemail" name="confemail" placeholder="youremail@mail.co.nz..." autocomplete='off' required>
                <br>
                <label for="phone">Contact Number:</label>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern='[0-9]{2-3}[0-9]{2-3}[0-9]{3-4}' placeholder='000 000 0000' autocomplete='tel-national' required>
                <br>
                <label for="address"> Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder='Your address...' autocomplete='address' required>
                <br>
                <label for="gender"> Gender:</label>
                <select name="gender" id="gender" autocomplete='gender' required>
                    <option value=''>Select...</option>
                    <option value="gen">Gender Diverse</option>
                    <option value="f">Female</option>
                    <option value="m">Male</option>
                    <option value="pnts">Prefer not to say</option>
                </select>
                <button class='center' type="submit" value='Signup'>Signup
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JS function-

```
function validateAndConfirm() {
    let firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    let lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let confemail = document.getElementById('confemail').value;
    let phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
    let address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    let gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    if (email == confemail) {
        alert('Your details have been submitted as below and your card will be sent out within the next 5 business days. /n First name: ' + firstname + ' /n Last name: ' + lastname + ' /n Email: ' + email + ' /n Phone ' + phone + ' /n Address: ' + address + ' /n Gender: ' + gender + '');
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Emails do not match, please amend and try again.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am expecting this to check the emails match and if true display alert box saying "Your details have been submitted as below and your card will be sent out within the next 5 business days.
First name: firstname entered
Last name: lastname entered
Email: email entered
Phone: phone entered
Address: address entered
Gender: gender entered

If false it would ask to check emails and try again.

Comment: Is the regex that you have for phone number meant to be [0-9]{2,3}[0-9]{2,3}[0-9]{3,4}

Comment: Im new to this so this was a suggested way to validate NZ phone numbers when entering data into the form - feel free to suggest a better option :)

Comment: Quantifiers in regular expressions which matches from n to m times. are of the format { n , m }. You have used a '-'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 errors:

1 - It is `onsubmit` not `onsumbmit`
2 - The function should be called like `validateAndConfirm()`
3 - The input button should be inside the form

Thus:

```
<form method='post' onsubmit='validateAndConfirm()'>
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Forgot to say thank you very much :) just starting out with Javascript so really appreciate the fast help and easy to understand instructions :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your submit button is outside the form so it doesn't try to submit the form.
2. Your attribute on the form says `onsumbmit` instead of `onsubmit`.

Move it inside the closing form tag and fix the `onsubmit` attributes:

```html
<form method='post' onsubmit='return validateAndConfirm()'>

  <!-- ...inputs... -->

  <button type="submit" value="Signup">Sign Up</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Ray :) I have moved the button inside the form tags however, when I enter emails that do not match there is no alert box - the same for if they do match - no alert box :(

Comment: You have `onsumbmit` instead of `onsubmit`. Answer updated.

Answer (score -1):

Because the form closing tag is not in the correct position and use strick equality operator(===)

```js
  function validateAndConfirm() {
    let firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    let lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let confemail = document.getElementById("confemail").value;
    let phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    let address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    let gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;

    if (email === confemail) {
      alert("Your details have been submitted as below and your card will be sent out within the next 5 business days.\n\nFirst name: " + firstname + "\nLast name: " + lastname + "\nEmail: " + email + "\nPhone: " + phone + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nGender: " + gender);
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("Emails do not match, please amend and try again.");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="form" class="center text">
  <form method="post" onsubmit="return validateAndConfirm()">
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Your first name..." autocomplete="given-name" required>
    <br>
    <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..." autocomplete="family-name" required>
    <br>
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@mail.co.nz..." autocomplete="off" required>
    <br>
    <label for="confemail">Confirm Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="confemail" name="confemail" placeholder="youremail@mail.co.nz..." autocomplete="off" required>
    <br>
    <label for="phone">Contact Number:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{2-3}[0-9]{2-3}[0-9]{3-4}" placeholder="000 000 0000" autocomplete="tel-national" required>
    <br>
    <label for="address"> Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Your address..." autocomplete="address" required>
    <br>
    <label for="gender"> Gender:</label>
    <select name="gender" id="gender" autocomplete="gender" required>
      <option value="">Select...</option>
      <option value="gen">Gender Diverse</option>
      <option value="f">Female</option>
      <option value="m">Male</option>
      <option value="pnts">Prefer not to say</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Signup</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Two things

1. `onsubmit` should be provided as an attribute to the `<form>` tag instead of `onclick` in button
2. Submit button should be inside the `<form>`

PS: I have added an `event.preventDefault()` inorder to avoid unnecessary page refresh on submit button click.

```js
function validateAndConfirm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Hello world')
  // Function
}
```

```html
<div id='form' class='center text' onsubmit="validateAndConfirm(event)">
    <form method='post'>
        <!-- All your controls -->
        <button class='center' type="submit" value="Signup">Signup
        </button>
    </form>
    
</div>
```